# My Tab View Fragement display Blank screen

Tags: android, gridview, tabs

first sorry for my bad English,In tab view my fragment was not show any content it display blank screen any one help me ,If i am trying to display any text its working fine when am trying to show grid view it will show blank page ,I cat log no errors

Tab1.java

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {
private GridviewAdapter mAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> listCountry;
private ArrayList<Integer> listFlag;

private GridView gridView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1,container,false);
    gridView = (GridView)v. findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    return v;
}


public void prepareList()
{
      listCountry = new ArrayList<String>();

      listCountry.add("india");
      listCountry.add("Brazil");
      listCountry.add("Canada");
      listCountry.add("China");



      listFlag = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      listFlag.add(R.drawable.india);
      listFlag.add(R.drawable.brazil);
      listFlag.add(R.drawable.canada);
      listFlag.add(R.drawable.china);

}
```

}

my adapter.java

```
public class GridviewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private ArrayList<String> listCountry;
private ArrayList<Integer> listFlag;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private static Context mcontext;


public GridviewAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> listCountry, ArrayList<Integer> listFlag) {
    super();
    this.listCountry = listCountry;
    this.listFlag = listFlag;
    this.mcontext = context;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return listCountry.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return listCountry.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
public static class ViewHolder
{
    public ImageView imgViewFlag;
    public TextView txtViewTitle;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder view;


    if(convertView==null)
    {
         inflater =  (LayoutInflater)mcontext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_one, null);

        view.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        view.imgViewFlag = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        convertView.setTag(view);
    }
    else
    {
        view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    view.txtViewTitle.setText(listCountry.get(position));
    view.imgViewFlag.setImageResource(listFlag.get(position));

    return convertView;
}
```

tab.xml

```
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"

    android:numColumns="2" />
```

gridviewrow.xml

```
<ImageView 
    android:layout_height="64dp" 
    android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
    android:layout_width="64dp" 

    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
</ImageView>

<TextView 
    android:text="TextView" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1" 
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"></TextView>
```

my tab adapter class

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

CharSequence Titles[]; // This will Store the Titles of the Tabs which are Going to be passed when ViewPagerAdapter is created
int NumbOfTabs; // Store the number of tabs, this will also be passed when the ViewPagerAdapter is created


// Build a Constructor and assign the passed Values to appropriate values in the class
public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,CharSequence mTitles[], int mNumbOfTabsumb) {
    super(fm);

    this.Titles = mTitles;
    this.NumbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;

}

//This method return the fragment for the every position in the View Pager
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    if(position == 0) // if the position is 0 we are returning the First tab
    {
        Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
        return tab1;
    }
    else             // As we are having 2 tabs if the position is now 0 it must be 1 so we are returning second tab
    {
        Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
        return tab2;
    }

}

// This method return the titles for the Tabs in the Tab Strip

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return Titles[position];
}

// This method return the Number of tabs for the tabs Strip

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NumbOfTabs;
}
```

}
below my empty screen this is my problem please any one help to resolve this problem

[image]